# How to limit ListView item length to prevent error

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm building this flutter app where i want to put to items of the same list with consecutive index values on the same row but I'm getting this error with the range of the list (which i had anticipated) but cant figure out the solution.  child: Image.asset(menuItemList[index+1].image)-> because of this line particularly when the menuItemList reaches its limit it adds + 1 to the index which goes out of the range.. I would like to know if there is another way of doing this or if I can use a if statement to limit the range

code

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:projectfooddelivery/Src/models/menu_item.dart';

List<MenuItem> menuItemList = [
  MenuItem(
      name: "Steak",
      image: "images/kfcfood.jpg",
      price: 8.99,
      icon: IconButton(
        icon: Icon(Icons.add_circle), color: Colors.deepOrange,
      )),
  MenuItem(name: "Steak", image: "images/kfcfood.jpg", price: 8.99, icon:IconButton(icon: IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.add_circle,color: Colors.deepOrange,size: 35,), onPressed: null), onPressed: null),),
  MenuItem(name: "Chips", image: "images/kfcfood.jpg", price: 30.99),
  MenuItem(name: "Steak", image: "images/kfcfood.jpg", price: 8.99),
  MenuItem(name: "Steak", image: "images/kfcfood.jpg", price: 8.99),
  MenuItem(name: "Steak", image: "images/kfcfood.jpg", price: 8.99),
  MenuItem(name: "Steak", image: "images/kfcfood.jpg", price: 8.99),
  MenuItem(name: "Steak", image: "images/kfcfood.jpg", price: 8.99),
  MenuItem(name: "Steak", image: "images/kfcfood.jpg", price: 8.99),
  MenuItem(name: "Steak", image: "images/kfcfood.jpg", price: 8.99),
];

class MenuWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 0),
        height: 200,
        child: ListView.builder(
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          itemCount: menuItemList.length,
          itemBuilder: (_, index) {
            return Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(6.0),
              child: Container(
                  child: Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    height: 150,
                    child: Stack(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        ClipRRect(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                            child: Image.asset(menuItemList[index].image)
                        ),
                        Align(
                          alignment: Alignment.center,
                          child: Column(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Text("bRO")
                            ],
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left:18.0),
                    child: Container(
                      height: 150,
                  child:
                      Stack(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          ClipRRect(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                              child: Image.asset(menuItemList[index+1].image)
                          ),
                          Align(
                            alignment: Alignment.center,
                            child: Column(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Text("Something")
                              ],
                            ),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              )),
            );
          },
        )
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use an `if` statement in the `itemBuilder` of the `ListView` and return `null` when the builder index is greater than your list length.

Something like

```
if(index >= menuItemList.length)
  return null;
```

should be in the `itemBuilder`.

Answer (score -1):

You can add the second item conditionally, using the `collection if` feature:

```dart
Row(
  children: <Widget>[
    Container(
      ...
    ),
    if (index + 1 < menuItemList.length) // <-- collection if
      Padding(
        ...
      )
  ],
)
```

Note: `collection if` is available from Dart 2.3 forward. See more about it [here](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#collection-operators).

Comment: "I would like to know if there is another way of doing this or if I can use a if statement to limit the range" - I've showed another way of doing the same but I will delete the answer if the OP confirm that I have misunderstood their question.

Comment: Just to clarify, someone wrote that I didn't answer the OP and I replied with the above but they have deleted their comment.

Comment: This corrects the error but its not doing exactly what I want because the first  child: Image.asset(menuItemList[index].image) reprints the same index I already printed with child: Image.asset(menuItemList[index+1].image).. I want to know if there is another way of puting the 2 pictures that come from the same listviewbuilder in the same row

Comment: I think I understand, so sorry about my previous answer. It seems that what you want can be achieved with a GridView.builder instead, but let me know if that's not correct as well.